# how to have pass-by-reference parameters for behavior methods in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, pass-by-reference, behavior

According to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#creating-behavior-methods,

I can do the following:

```
public function fly(Model $Model, $from, $to) {
    // Do some flying.
}
```

I want to have a passed-by-reference parameter in the behavior method.

This is my method:

```
public function extractByFields(Model $model, $data, $options = array(), Array $missingFields) {
```

the parameter I want to be passed by reference is `$missingFields`.

Reason is because I want to return my `$foundFields` but in case there are any other missing fields, I also want to expose them to the method caller.

If CakePHP cannot allow me to return passed-by-reference parameters in my behavior methods, I would like some advice on how best to have a workaround?

My version is CakePHP2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With behavior methods you cannot use pass-by-reference parameters. call_user_func_array() is used to call the methods and the arguments are not passed by reference.

Possible workaround: store missing fields in the Behavior class as an attribute and have a method to retrieve them.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I adopted the workaround suggested by Ceeram. I stored $missingFields as a private attribute and retrieve them with a separate method